# How do I write static blocks in Xtend?

Tags: express, xtend, static-block

Just like in Java：

```java
static {

}
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extend currently doesn't support static initializers - see https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=429141.

One possible workaround is to create a field you don't care about just for the side-effects of the initializer:

```java
static val I_AM_ONLY_FOR_SIDE_EFFECTS = {
  // Code you'd want in your static initializer
  return 0
}
```